# Google Chrome - crash under windows when iframe and youtube is used but not crashing same code in Linux

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, crash, window

Same code, same Google chrome versions. 
Under Linux Google Chrome is working but with Windows Google Chrome crashing. Tested with 30 Windows PC all crash, tested with 10 Linux PC all works with same code.

How to fix it?

[image]

```
<div id="video_window" class="video_window" style="
     ">  
    <div style="font-size: 18px;color:white;text-align: right;
         padding-right: 5px; 
         padding-top:2px;
         font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;">X</div>

    <iframe id="video_one" class="video_frame" style="z-index: 0;" width="800" height="600" 
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/asdfasfdsf-Q?rel=0" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <iframe id="video_two"  class="video_frame" style="z-index: 0;" width="800" height="600" 
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/asdfafasfdsf?rel=0" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>



</div>
```

Comment: start eliminating things. change the iframe urls to something that DOESN'T use flash (e.g. a plain static html page) and track down what's causing the crash. remove an iframe, swap the order they're in, etc...

Comment: Linux when i use version: Version 33.0.1750.146 it works Windows when i use Version 34 its causing it.

Comment: so they're NOT the same versions...

Comment: I just changed it when you suggested me to track everything. so first thing i did is swap the versions to lower and then the problem is instantly identified. that with version 33 it works but with 34 crash in Linux, Mac, Windows.

Comment: FYI - Linux Version 34.0.1847.132 is working, Windows Version: 34.0.1847.131 m crashing

Comment: Google Canary after installing seems its resolved in M36

Answer (score 1):

As You can see same block of code worked in my "Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114" Running under Windows 8.
It maybe something else that is wrong there.

```
<div id="video_window" class="video_window" style="">  
<div style="font-size: 18px;color:white;text-align: right;
     padding-right: 5px; 
     padding-top:2px;
     font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;">X</div>

<iframe id="video_one" class="video_frame" style="z-index: 0;" width="800" height="600" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-hffP2vr1Jk" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe id="video_two"  class="video_frame" style="z-index: 0;" width="800" height="600" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RNOM8ei08pc" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot:1]
[image: Screenshot:2]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen with Google Chrome Version 102.0.5005.63 (Official Build) (64-bit), and it was fixed after clearing the browser cache.